# Angebenen: does it actually exist as a word?

Tags: meaning, adjective

I was reading a Sputnik article about Nawalny's alleged poisoning when I came across a sentence:

> Diese Substanz wurden von der Berliner Charité in dem ersten Befund angebenen und bestärkte die deutschen Ärzte in ihrer Annahme, es handle sich im Fall Nawalny um eine Vergiftung.

which obviously should read either *Substanz wurde* or *Substanzen wurden*, but what really bothers me is "angebenen", whereof I can't figure out the meaning.

Here's the link: https://de.sputniknews.com/panorama/20200904327881609-nawalny-keine-giftstoffe-toxikologe/

Comment: I suppose it should have been “angegeben”.

Comment: One way to figure this out is to type the sentence into Google translate, then hit the Swap Languages button (the two arrows between the original and the translation). Google is pretty good at figuring out questionable grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't exist. It's a typo and should read:

> Diese Substanz wurde [...] angegeben [...]

You can find it in this [Wiktionary flexion table](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:angeben) at

```
 Präteritum > Vorgangspassiv > Indikativ > 3. Person Singular
```